# Cross Site duplicate entry prevention

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, cross-site

I've 2 sites within my SharePoint 2013 Site Collection: Site A and Site B. 
I've one field that needs to check either site to see if that text entry exists on that either site.

For example if I put in "Bob" in an entry and try to save it to the list in *Site A*, it would look up *Site B* and check and see if "Bob" exists, and vice versa. If it exists in either site list it will not let the user save the new entry.

Can this be done, and how?

Answer (score 0):

If you have Sharepoint Designer, you could do a poor mans temporary solution and write a Workflow to check if the item exists in the other list and if it does delete the entry and notify the Created By that it was deleted with a link to the existing item.

Comment: Unfortunately that is not an option I can go with. It needs to check on the save button like if you were to have the same entry on the site already and it lets you know it already exists.

Comment: you MIGHT be able to use the Validation function on the column if your two lists contained a column that was the values from the other list (you'd have to manually populate it first but then could use a simple workflow to update the next record in the target list that had a blank value)